# How to fix repeated message replies in Smooch Python API?

Tags: python, python-requests, smooch

I've got my code setup to send a series of messages based on a keyword sent by the App User.

e.g If the user sends the keyword "TEST", they will receive a series of text messages configured to respond to that keyword.

When I have a keyword with 4 or fewer response messages, the response message is only sent once.

Problem is, if the keyword has more than 4 response messages, the response message is sent multiple times. Each message series is sent 5 times and the sender ends up with 20 responses (4x5)

```
class SmoocherMessages(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt) # required
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        incoming_message = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

        log = SmoocherLog(msg_plain=incoming_message)
        log.save()


        return HttpResponse("OK", status=200)

@receiver(post_save, sender=SmoocherLog)
def process_smoocher_post(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #Get the JSON
        sm_post = instance.msg_plain
        print("SIGNAL TRIGGERRED")
        process_smoocher_message(data=sm_post)



def process_smoocher_message(data):
    # Remove all punctuations, lower case the text and split it based on space
    entry = None
    key_word = None
    smapp_id = None
    sender = None
    client = "dbc5994d"
    cust = Customer.objects.get(account_id=client)
    rez_agent_name = cust.company_name
    if cust.agent_name:
        rez_agent_name = cust.agent_name
    if cust.agent_avatar:
        rez_agent_avatar = cust.agent_avatar

    if data['trigger']:
        entry = data['trigger']
        if entry == "message:appUser":
            smapp_id = data['app']['_id']
            sender = data['appUser']['_id']
            if data['messages']:
                msg_full = data['messages'][0]
                if msg_full['type'] == "text":
                    #Process the keyword
                    #Strip Spaces and any special characters
                    msg_raw = msg_full['text']
                    msg_cl = re.sub('\W+',' ', msg_raw)
                    msg = msg_cl.strip()

                #TRY TO FIND THE KEYWORD
                    try:
                        key_word = CustomerKeyword.objects.get(customer=client,keyword__iexact=msg)

                    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                        # log2 = FBLogger(msg_plain="No Keyword Found, Exception Raised")

                        default_msg = "INVALID"
                        key_word = CustomerKeyword.objects.get(customer=client,keyword__iexact=default_msg)
                    #GET THE RESPONSE SEQUENCE
                    req_seq = KeywordSequence.objects.filter(keyword=key_word).order_by('sequence')
                    api_instance = smooch.ConversationApi()
                    app_id = smapp_id
                    user_id = sender
                    conversation_activity_body = None
                    if rez_agent_name:
                        rez_name = rez_agent_name
                        rez_avatar = rez_agent_avatar
                        conversation_activity_body_start = smooch.ConversationActivity(role='appMaker', type='typing:start', name=rez_name, avatar_url=rez_avatar)
                        conversation_activity_body_stop = smooch.ConversationActivity(role='appMaker', type='typing:stop', name=rez_name, avatar_url=rez_avatar)
                    else:
                        conversation_activity_body = smooch.ConversationActivity(role='appMaker', type='typing:start')
                    api_instance.conversation_activity(app_id, user_id, conversation_activity_body_start)
                    for x in req_seq:
                        msg_rez = x.msg.msg_plain

                        if msg_full['source']['type'] == "whatsapp":
                            msg_rez = x.msg.msg_rich

                        if x.msg.msg_type == "Chat":
                            # create an instance of the API class
                            message_post_body1 = smooch.MessagePost(text=msg_rez, role='appMaker', type='text', name=rez_name, avatar_url=rez_avatar)
                            time.sleep(3)
                            api_response = api_instance.post_message(app_id, user_id, message_post_body1)
                            time.sleep(2)

                        if x.msg.msg_type == "Link":
                            # create an instance of the API class
                            response_msg = json.dumps({"text":msg_rez, "role": "appMaker", "type": "text", "actions": [{"type": "link", "text": x.msg.attachment_description, "uri": x.msg.attachment_url}]})

                            authk = "Bearer " + smooch_jwt
                            endpoint = "https://api.smooch.io/v1.1/apps/" + app_id + "/appusers/" + user_id + "/messages"

                            status = requests.post(
                                endpoint,
                                headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "authorization": authk},
                                data=response_msg)
                            print("WE HAVE POSTED THE LINK")
                            time.sleep(3)

                        if x.msg.msg_type == "Image":
                            # create an instance of the API class
                            act = {}
                            act['uri'] = str(x.msg.attachment_url)
                            act['type'] = "link"
                            act['text'] = x.msg.attachment_description
                            message_post_body = smooch.MessagePost(text=msg_rez, role='appMaker', type='image', media_url=x.msg.attachment_url, actions=act, name=rez_name, avatar_url=rez_avatar)

                            api_response = api_instance.post_message(app_id, user_id, message_post_body)
                            time.sleep(2)

                        if x.msg.msg_type == "File":
                            # create an instance of the API class

                            message_post_body2 = smooch.MessagePost(text=msg_rez, role='appMaker', type='file', media_url=x.msg.attachment_url, name=rez_name, avatar_url=rez_avatar)

                            api_response = api_instance.post_message(app_id, user_id, message_post_body2)
                            time.sleep(2)
                    api_instance.conversation_activity(app_id, user_id, conversation_activity_body_stop)

    return None
```

Comment: You have a lot of code here, are there chunks you can get rid of while still reproducing the error? Here are some tips on doing so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll follow the link and try to get rid of any chunks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Smooch API docs](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#retry-policy)

> If no response is received within 20 seconds, the call will be considered a failure and will also be reattempted.

It looks like you're doing lots of processing in your webhook handler and only returning once the processing is complete. With the `time.sleep` in between calls to the Smooch API, it's very likely that your handler is exceeding the 20 second timeout window, causing Smooch to consider the delivery as a failure and reattempt the webhook call. You can confirm this in the Smooch web dashboard under the `Logs` tab for your app, you should see a number of webhooks `attempted` instead of `delivered`.

Your code should return 200 OK as soon as you can confirm receipt of the payload. Any processing you do afterwards should happen in the background once the call from Smooch has been acknowledged.

Comment: Your suggestion worked!! Thank you. I eliminated all the `time.sleep` and also modified 'HttpResponse("OK",status=200) to HttpResponse(status=200)`